# prove spectral equivalence bounds for inverse fractional power of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, sp.spectral-theory, fractional-calculus

The question is an extention to the answered question [prove spectral equivalence bounds for fractional power of matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425375/prove-spectral-equivalence-bounds-for-fractional-power-of-matrices).

Let $A, D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two symmetric,positive definite and tri-diagonal matrices  for that we know that they are spectrally equivalent, thus ist holds
$$ c^- x^\top D x \le x^\top A x \le c^+ x^\top D x $$
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $c^+, c^- > 0.$ The matrices $A$ and $D$ can be diagonalized, that is $$ A = V\Lambda_A V^\top, \quad D = W\Lambda_D W^\top $$
where $V$ and $W$ contain the eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$, and $\Lambda_A$ and $\Lambda_D$ are diagonal matrices containing the respective eigenvalues.
Based on the Reileigh quotient, it should follow that
$$ cond(D^{-1}A) \le \frac{c^+}{c^-},$$
thus $c^+$ and $c^-$ upper and lower bounds for the range of the eigenvalues of $D^{-1}A.$

In the question I linked above, I got the answer that due to Loewner's theorem, for $0 < \alpha \le 1,$
$$ (c^-)^\alpha x^\top D^\alpha x \le x^\top A^\alpha x \le (c^+)^\alpha x^\top D^\alpha x $$
does hold. Here, $A^\alpha := V\Lambda_A^\alpha V^\top,$ and $D^\alpha := W\Lambda_D^\alpha W^\top,$ where $\Lambda_A^\alpha, \Lambda_D^\alpha$ can be computed by taking the power $\alpha$ of each diagonal entry.

**Now my question is:**

Is it possible to deduce the spectral bound estimates for the inverse of the matrices, that is for $A^{-1}$ and $D^{-1}$ as well as $A^{-\alpha}$ and $D^{-\alpha}$ in the same manner ? I expect something like, e.g.,
$$\frac{1}{c^+} x^\top D^{-1} x \le x^\top A^{-1} x \le \frac{1}{c^-} x^\top D^{-1} x $$
and $$\frac{1}{(c^+)^\alpha} x^\top D^{-\alpha} x \le x^\top A^{-\alpha} x \le \frac{1}{(c^-)^\alpha} x^\top D^{-\alpha} x $$
that holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

And second: Is it possible to deduce the condition numbers for $(D^{-1} A)$ and $(D^{-\alpha} A^\alpha)$ from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Remark 1 after Theorem 4.1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-22422-6), the matrix expression $-A^{-\alpha}$ is Loewner-nondecreasing in positive definite matrix $A$ if and only $0\le\alpha\le1$.

So, the inequalities
$$\frac{1}{(c^+)^\alpha} x^\top D^{-\alpha} x \le x^\top A^{-\alpha} x \le \frac{1}{(c^-)^\alpha} x^\top D^{-\alpha} x $$
will hold in general if and only $0\le\alpha\le1$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have seen that remark, but in proposition 2.2 (to which they refer in that remark) they state that in that case, the eigenvalues of both A and D have to be in (-1,0). In our case, due to positive definiteness of A and D, this does obviously not hold. So the statement does not hold?

Comment: @Luna947 : You should apply Proposition 2.2 with $A,B$ replaced by $-A,-B$, or by $-A^{-1},-B^{-1}$. In other words, if $0<A\le B$ (in the Loewner sense), then $A^{-1}\ge B^{-1}$ -- which is what one should use here.

Comment: ok, so I still have one question: in our case, $A$ and $B$ have eigenvalues in (0,\infty ). so the eigenvalues of $-A$ and $-B$ are in (-\infty ,0) and for $-A^{-1}$ and $-B^{-1}$ they are in in (-\infty ,0) and (-\infty ,0). How can I now deduce the statement using Proposition 2.2 since there it is neccessary to have the eigenvalues in the range $(-1,0)$ ?

Comment: And let me come up with another question - i think that should be the last one! Is it possible to make a statement concerning the spectral equivalence estimates of the sum, e.g., something like $(A+A^{-1}) \le \max\{c^+, \frac{1}{c^+}\} (D + D^{-1})$ based on the bounds that we deduced so far??

Comment: @Luna947 : no, this is impossible.

Comment: sorry maybe i formulated the constant to sloppy. We know $x^\top A x \le c^+ x^\top D x$ and $x^\top A^{-1} x \le \frac{1}{c^-} x^\top D^{-1} x$ holds. Doesn't the addition of both inequalities yield $x^\top (A+A^{-1}) x = x^\top A x + x^\top A^{-1} x \le c^+ x^\top D x + \frac{1}{c^-} x^\top D^{-1} x \le \max\{c^+, 1/c^-\} x^\top (D + D^{-1}) x$ ?

Comment: @Luna947 : now this is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fruitful information that you provided to me. It was really interesting learning about Loewner's theorem and a great help for closing some remaining gaps in my thesis!

Comment: @Luna947 : you are welcome.